# Can you provide tips to implement a simple control system in an OOP Approach?

Tags: c#, oop, if-statement, controls, clock

I'm writing a complex control system for several machines. I'm using C# for convenience, since no true-real time is required, just fast response.

My question is regarding the sampling of sensors in the physical controlled systems: I want to perform actions depending on their values (e.g. if the temperature drops below X do Action A, if the pressure is higher than Y do action B).

There's the simple loop-with-value-querying approach, and there's the option to implement a clock that periodically (hmmm, every 0.01 second) checks the value of about 50 different sensors.

Any finer, more efficient, smarter, more OOP-ish approaches?

Thanks!

Comment: Pls. provide some more Detail. How do you poll the sensor data? Database or sth.?

Comment: Hi. I'm pulling my sensor data using National Instruments' data acquisition tools, which include libraries for many languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your question is very broad and IMO it is impossible to answer it in a way you would expect. The only advice I can give is to learn about object oriented design which, in my case, happens to be a continous process which might never end.

There is some literature I can definitely recommend if you want to do so:

1. **Agile Principles, Patterns and Practices in C#** - How can I design Software in an object oriented manner? (probably exactly what you need)
2. **Clean Code** - what does code look like that is easily understandable, maintainable and extendable?
3. **Clean Coder** - this focusses on daily issues when developing software. (how to work in a developers-team, how to deal with managers etc, sounds boring at first, but i was surprised and this helped me a ton)

All the books are by Robert C. Martin.

Learn about [SOLID-Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), why they are important and how to apply them correctly. Dive into [Design Patterns of the GOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) which solve common problems every developer stumbles upon sooner or later. Booth of those points are explained in the first book I recommended.

I know this is not what you expected, but given the little detail and the broadness of you question, this is all i can give.

Regarding the polling, the only thing that comes to my mind would be to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and subscribe to the [`PropertyChanged`-event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) if that is possible. This would be an Observer-like approach.